# Bending an elastic, inextensible sheet of paper into a teardrop shape

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I take an rectangular sheet of paper, of height $H$ and Young's Modulus $E$, and in the absence of gravity, I bend it into a "teardrop" shape so that the edges along the top and bottom touch only along a single line.

What analytic function describes this "teardrop" shape?

Comment: Are you specifying the boundary condition that the tangent cones of the edges coincide, or that they form some specified dihedral angle?

Comment: You may find this question on MSE useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51539/a-math-function-that-draws-water-droplet-shape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All in here (if using Euler Bernoulli beam theory)

http://sci-toys.com/bent_paper_problem.pdf

---

(*Added by Joseph O'Rourke*).  Here is Fig.1 from the paper by Antoni Colom,
 "Analysis of the shape of a sheet of paper when two opposite edges are joined," PDF link above.

        
[image: Tear Drop]

Comment: @Paul: I took the liberty of adding detail to your answer.